# Does $e^n$ still have the commutative property of $e$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Where $e$ is the identity element and $n$ is a real number.

First session abstract algebra here. I came across potentially using this to complete a proof, but I'm not sure if it would be correct. I thought it could be possible as $e$ to the power of a positive integer is also $e$. 
I'm specifically curious about whether root $e$ would be commutative or not.

Comment: What do you mean?  Are you asking is $a*e^n = e^n*a$?  Yes.  Because $e^n = e$.  More techinical, By associativity $(((((a*e)*e)*e)*e .....) = a*((((((e*e)*e)*e)*e =...= a*e = a = e*a =....= ((((((((e*e)*e)*e).... *)*a$.  But anyway, if $a*b$ have some property and $b = c$ then $a*c$ has the property because $a*b$ and $a*c$ are the same thing because $b$ and $c$ are the same thing.  S $e^n = e$ so whatever you say about $e$, you can say about $e^n$.

Comment: I was asking that, sorry if it wasn't clear - I just wasn't too sure whether the n had to be a positive integer since I'd only seen it as such. Thanks!

Comment: Oh!  That's a good question.  In group theory, a negative power, $a^{-n}$ means the inverse of $a$ (call it $a'$) the $n$th power.  Since $(a')^n = (a^n)'$ and $(a')^n*(a')^m = (a')^{n+m} = (a^{n+m})'$ and $a^n*(a')^m = a^{n-m}$ we call $a' := a^{-1}$ and we have $(a^{-1})^n = (a^n)^{-1}$ so we call it $a^{-n}$.  As $e*e=e$ we know $e=e'=e^{-1}$ and $e^n = e^{-n} = e$.  It is *all* good.

Comment: Okay, $e^x$ where $x$ is irrational is not definable by only group definitions. And $e^q$ where $q$ is rational is definable as $a^{\frac mn}$ is the solution to $x^n = a^m$ but is not nesc. unique nor nescessarily exists.  But we can assume if $e^x$ is meaningful,, then $e^x = e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^n = e$ so $e^n$ commutes with other elements because it is $e$

Note that $e^2 = e$ so in a sense, $e$ is it's own square root. However, as pointed out in the comments, there may be other elements which square to the identity (for example, a reflection in a group of isometries), so it doesn't necessarily make sense to talk about a square root of $e$.

Comment: $e^{1/2}$ is not even _defined_ yet, and when it is, it may be defined so as to have multiple values, for some of which $e^{1/2}\ne e$.

Comment: I didn't even think of uniqueness! Can you give an example?

Comment: Ever seen any finite groups?

Comment: fixed it ......

Comment: e=$y^2$ and e=$x^4$ in the textbook, so I was just assuming it is a number.

Comment: example: any group with an $a \ne e$ so that $a^2 = e$.  There are many.  $\mathbb Z_2 = \langle \{0,1\}, + \rangle| 0+0=0; 0+1=1+0=1; 1+1 =0$ is the simplest example.

Comment: $e = y^2$ may have many solutions.  In $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ under multiplication (which is a group).  $e =1$ and $e=y^2$ can have $1$ and $-1$ as solutions.  And $e = y^4$ may have $1, -1, i, -i$ as solution.  Finite groups have some good ones.  In $\mathbb Z_n$ under modular addition and $n$ is composite.  $a^k = 0$ will be solved by any $a$ so that $a*k$ is a multiple of $n$. Example if $n=8$ then $0=2^4=4^8=6^4=0^4$.  (Note $a^4$ means $a + a +a +a$.)

Comment: Should also note $a^{\frac 1n}$ need not exist at all.  In $\mathbb Z_8$, $3^{\frac 14}$ does not exist as there is no value $a$ so that $a^4 = 3$